# How to extract the numbers from this input string

Tags: python, regex, string, list, numbers

If I have an input string:

```
a = 'W1 W2 W3 W4 W5 W6 W7 W8 W9 W10 W11'
```

How to extract the numbers and store in a list? For example

```
numList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

I have tried doing it like this:

```
[int(t) for t in a if t.isdigit()]
```

This only works for the single digit numbers, but doesn't work for the double digit numbers.

Comment: `import re;re.findall(r'\d+', a)`

Answer (score 2):

You can split by space and then slice the first character of every item out:

```
>>> [int(item[1:]) for item in a.split()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

---

You can also, if applicable (do not know the origin and possible variations of the input string), just remove the `W` from the string and split:

```
>>> a = a.replace("W", "")
>>> [int(item) for item in a.split()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regex:

```
import re
numList = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
```